# как запустить мой браузер, через селениум

Tags: java, selenium

есть мой браузер, в котором я работаю, и мне нужно запустить его через селениум

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Там проблема в том что нужно подобрать конкретную версию вебдрайвера/Selenium  и браузера.
Советую отключить автообновление браузера - или скачать старую версию браузера. 
С самыми новыми версиями браузера Selenium может не работать. Остальное как по документации. Еще раньше помогало иногда использование 32 битных браузеров если были проблемы с подключением к браузеру у selenium.
Можно как альтернативу использовать Selenide - у них на сайте очень понятные инструкции и быстро можно запустить.

Comment: а вообще, код можете написать, для любой версии браузера, что бы я примерно понимал, куда мне идти, просто код. где запускается браузер по моему пути , например "C://hoha//shrome.exe"